# Autocomplete ajax g.nodename is undefined

Tags: function, jquery-autocomplete

I'm new here, and I'm having a problem with ajax autocomplete, I get this error with Firebug (in Firefox):

> g.nodeName is undefined
>   c=f.valHooks[g.type]||f.valHooks[g.nodeName.toLowerCase()];
>   jquery....min.js (linha 977)

and in Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined jquery-1.7.2.min.js:977
>   f.fn.extend.val jquery-1.7.2.min.js:977
>   $.autocomplete.source novo:77
>   a.widget._search jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js:127
>   a.widget.search jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js:127
>   (anonymous function)

Can someone help me with that, I'm using jQuery 1.7.2-min complete, and I followed this tutorial http://www.jensbits.com/2011/08/24/using-jquery-autocomplete-when-remote-source-json-does-not-contain-label-or-value-fields/

My json source returns code above:

```
[{"id":"1","campo":"[1] Empresa Tal"},{"id":"2","campo":"[2] Outra Empresa Tal"},{"id":"3","campo":"[3] Mais Outra Empresa"}]
```

My javascript function:

```
 $('#accadempresa').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax.php?action=available&orm=cadempresa&campo=razsoc&valor=' + $(this).val(),
                dataType: "json",
                data: {term: request.term},
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            id: item.id,
                            campo: item.campo
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert('ae');
            //$('#state_id').val(ui.item.id);
            //$('#abbrev').val(ui.item.abbrev);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Try adding "async: false" to ajax call.

Comment: not works, see my page: http://pastebin.com/wj3gyA2n

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hello Sir i think you are getting this error because you are using $(this).val();
Replace that code with you id $(your element id).val().

```
$('#accadempresa').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax.php?action=available&orm=cadempresa&campo=razsoc&valor=' + $(elementid).val(),
                dataType: "json",
                data: {term: request.term},
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            id: item.id,
                            campo: item.campo
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert('ae');
            //$('#state_id').val(ui.item.id);
            //$('#abbrev').val(ui.item.abbrev);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Even though it's been ~10 years, I'd like to offer an explanation why this wasn't working for the OP. When `$(this)` is used like the OP did, that will actually refer to the object to which the `autocomplete` is attached, but to the immediate parent (the thing calling the `$.ajax` - `source: function(...)`).